# How can I create a Postgres database in Perl?

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi

How can I create a Postgres database from Perl? This is not documented in the Perl Postgres DBI driver [`DBD::Pg`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Pg) (or pretty much anywhere else). I need to be able to create a scratch database from my program, rather than having to use **psql** or **pgAdmin** to create the database.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is using the 'postgres' database that you will likely have with your installation of Postgres (if you don't have a 'postgres' database, you probably know why). If you connect as user 'postgres' to the 'postgres' database, you can then issue then **create database** SQL command, like so:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=postgres", "postgres");
$dbh->do('create database "Scratch-School"');
```

(You might also look at [create a postgreSQL database programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501971/create-a-postgresql-database-programmatically), which covers this issue at a higher level.)

Comment: You should stay away from quoted identifiers like `"Scratch-School"`. Many tools have problems with that. Better use `create database scratch_school` making the name case-insensitive and doesn't require you to write those double quotes every time.

Comment: The point is that to create a database, you need to be connected first to another existing database. It doesn't have to be `postgres`, and it's not specific to Perl. It's true even with `psql`, and even for `createdb` itself.